# How to change table/field name in Laravel Eloquent/Illuminate ORM mapping?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5, illuminate-container

I know that is it possible to use object and object field names (in Java Entity JPA/Hibernate ORM mappings) that are different from database table names and field names. Is it possible to configure Laravelt to allow different object and filed names? E.g. my database use uppercase names with underscore but I would like to use CamelCase object and field names in my PHP and JavaScript code.

Comment: yes the table fields are completely up to you. by default laravel tries to autoamtically find the tables for you from the models name you provide. Typically if you model is called User, laravel will try to look for users table. however you can override this on the model by adding the following property to the class `protected $table = 'your_table'`

Comment: read the documentation is pretty slick and laravel's ORM is amazing